# Git rebase going back to feature start

Tags: java, git, rebase

I would like to do a pull request, but found out that master is ahead of feature branch.

So i do

```
git checkout master
git pull
git git checkout feature
git rebase origin/master
```

and boom, i get conflict message ( expected ) but rebase will also overwrite every single change i made in my feature branch and overwrites them with months old code from feature branch... ( code that comes with rebase is not in *any* branch afaik ) with commit message from start of the feature branch.

rebase will also delete all of my new classes, which can't possibly conflict with master.
Both local and remote master and feature are uptodate, and show expected code. But as soon as i do rebase.

So rebase wants me to do all 82 commits and conflicts instead of the latest commit ?

I simply want to apply my **latest** code and commit to master, with PR. I dont want useless code from months ago when somebody else started this feature and forgot to rebase....

Is this possible ?

Comment: That you are 82 commits behind the remote `master` branch is a problem by itself, and most likely means that you have not been doing a good job of synching with that branch.  In a situation like this, I would actually recommend just doing a single merge with `origin/master` rather than a rebase.  Instead of getting changes and conflicts in dribs and drabs, as each of the 82 commits is painfully applied to your rebased feature branch, you will just a single merge commit.  This doesn't get you out of the woods necessarily, and you still may have too many merge conflicts to proceed.

Comment: Im well aware, this is more like case of me saving someone else tho..

Comment: Try the merge option, and see if you can work with it.  If you _can_, then go with it.  If not, then it may not matter which poison you take, in either case, your feature branch is just too far out of sync with the remote `master`.  The remedy for this going forward is to not work on a feature branch for days (weeks?) without synching with `master`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout your feature branch and pull from `master` into your `feature` branch. Resolve any conflicts if you have and then merge it to `master`. This way you will not loose any commits from your `feature branch`.

```
git checkout feature-branch
git pull origin master
#resolve any conflicts if you get
git commit
git push
#pull request should be updated with your master branch contents now
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? *I would like to get my feature branch to be rebased onto master but I really don't care about the history of my feature branch... all I would like to care about is the latest code at the tip of my branch*, then you could do this trick to merge/squash (without actually squashing):

```
git checkout my-branch
git merge origin/master # mix my code with master... don't worry about the merge or the history, we will turn it into a single revision on our next step
git reset --soft origin/master # here's the magic... all the history is gone, all we have now is your differences from origin/master on index and the branch is pointing to origin/master
git commit -m "My feature, in a single revision"
```

There you go